# Запрос даты рождения и вывод количества прожитых дней

Tags: javascript, html5

Нужно создать HTML-страницу, которая при загрузке запрашивает дату вашего рождения и выводит в текстовое поле формы количество дней, которые Вы прожили.

Не получается, как по условию нужно. Выводит просто дату рождения.

```js
var year = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ ГОД РОЖДЕНИЯ (в формате YYYY)'));
var month = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ НОМЕР МЕСЯЦ РОЖДЕНИЯ'));
var day = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ ДЕНЬ РОЖДЕНИЯ'));

if ((year.toString().length != 4) 
    || (month < 1 || month > 12) 
    || (day < 1 || day > 31)
) throw new Error('invalid date');

var arDay = ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среду', 'четверг', 'пятницу', 'субботу'];
var arMonth = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];

var date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day);

document.body.innerHTML = "Я\040родился\040" + 
                          day + "\040" + arMonth[(month - 1)] + "\040" + 
                          year + "\040в\040" + arDay[date.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var year = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ ГОД РОЖДЕНИЯ (в формате YYYY)'));
var month = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ НОМЕР МЕСЯЦ РОЖДЕНИЯ'));
var day = parseInt(prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ ДЕНЬ РОЖДЕНИЯ'));

if ((year.toString().length != 4) 
    || (month < 1 || month > 12) 
    || (day < 1 || day > 31)
) throw new Error('invalid date');

var arDay = ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среду', 'четверг', 'пятницу', 'субботу'];
var arMonth = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];

var date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day),
    currentDate = new Date(),
    days = Math.round((currentDate - date)/86400000);

document.body.innerHTML = "Я\040родился\040" + 
                          day + "\040" + arMonth[(month - 1)] + "\040" + 
                          year + "\040в\040" + arDay[date.getDay()] + "\040 " + days + " д. назад";
```